# Capture Console log error in Chrome through selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I'm using the following code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogType;

import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ChromeConsoleLogging {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");        
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
        logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public void analyzeLog() {
        LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
        for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
            System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
            //do something useful with the data
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        driver.get("http://mypage.com");
        //do something on page
        analyzeLog();
    }
}
```

But this line:

```
LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
```

Gives the following error:

> The method `logs()` is undefined for the type `WebDriver.Options()`.

The same code was working, but now it is throwing the error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is `\`enter code here\`` really in your code? String should be encoded with `"` and you're also missing a `+`.

Comment: sorry, `enter code here` got added while posting.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexander said, it's a problem with the unwanted string in middle of that line. I tried this in my system. it working fine. Please remove "enter code here" and try again.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; //avaiable
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; //available
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries;//yes
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry;//yes
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogType;//yes
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences;//yes
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;//yes
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;//yes
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;//yes
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;//yes
import org.testng.annotations.Test;//yes

public class Test123 {  //give your class name


 private WebDriver driver;



@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\Drivers\\chromedriverwin32\\chromedriver.exe");        
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}

public void analyzeLog() {
    LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
    for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
        System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
        //do something useful with the data
    }
}


@Test
 public  void testMethod() {
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        //do something on page
        analyzeLog();
    }


}
```

Comment: can you please tell which version of selenium are you using. That part was put by mistake while posting. In my system it throws the error message "the method logs() is undefined for the type webdriver.options"

Comment: Selenium Version: selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0

Comment: Hi Guna Yuvan, can you please post the working code.

Comment: @Chiranjib, use recent driver (i used recent chrome driver)